# Postgresql, bulk insert if row with some value not exists

Tags: postgresql

I want to do bulk insert only if there is no matching email

I tried this, but I don't know how to add a where clause.

```
INSERT INTO user (
   'pk',
   'email'
)
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]),
      UNNEST(ARRAY['example1@example.com', 'example2@example.com', .........])
WHERE something.......
```

Comment: your example should work (with a couple modifications) -- could you share the error message that you see, in addition to the actual query that you're trying to do it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample 1:

```
with tbl(a,b) as (
select
    UNNEST(ARRAY[10, 11, 12]),
    UNNEST(ARRAY['example3@example.com', 'example4@example.com', 'example5@example.com'])
)
insert into user (pk, email)
select a, b from tbl 
left join user on tbl.b = user.email 
where user.email is null
```

Sample 2:

```
with tbl(a,b) as (
select
    UNNEST(ARRAY[10, 11, 12]),
    UNNEST(ARRAY['example3@example.com', 'example4@example.com', 'example5@example.com'])
)
insert into user (pk, email)
select a, b from tbl 
where not exists (select 1 from user where user.email = tbl.b)
```